# Необъяснимый редирект nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

Не понимаю, почему nginx перенаправляет на основной домен с поддомена, имея явную конфигурацию:

```
    server {
    server_name launcher.myprod.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/launcher.myprod.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/launcher.myprod.com/privkey.pem;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    index index.php index.html;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/launcher.myprod.com;
    root $root_path;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    location / {
        root /home/launcher/5171/updates;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9274/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout     100;
        proxy_send_timeout        100;
        proxy_read_timeout        100;
        send_timeout              100;
    }
}
```

launcher.myprod.com ==> myprod.com ==> error

Comment: `sudo nginx -t` не пишет ничего интересного?

Comment: Увы:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: Вы на 100% уверены что это nginx делает redirect, а не Ваше приложение ?

Comment: Да, уверен, приложение не может делать редиректы.

Comment: http+s оба редиректят?

Comment: Проверьте `curl`-ом. Браузер мог закэшировать неправильный редирект.

Comment: `root@srv1:~# curl --ssl https://launcher.myprod.com/
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.2</center>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: DNS точно правильный? Что показывает `sudo nginx -T`?

Comment: `sudo nginx -T` Выдаёт nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
С последующим выведением всех конфигов nginx